# Взаимодействие с процессом через анонимные трубы (WinAPI)

Tags: winapi, c, c++

Здравствуйте.

Играюсь с винапи и возникла проблема которую не могу решить(

Суть такая. Хочу из программы запустить дочерний процесс, взаимодействие с которым будет проходить через трубы

Есть код:

```
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    si.hStdInput = rp_in;
    si.hStdError = wp_out;
    si.hStdOutput = wp_out;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    ret = CreateProcess(NULL,
            "cmd.exe",
            NULL,
            NULL,
            false,
            NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &si,
            &pi);
```

Где:
rp_in хендл одного из анонимных пайпов на чтение

wp_out хендл второго пайпа для записи

если запускать скомпилированную программу из под wine всё работает замечательно, если же запустить ис под wine дочерний процесс сразу же завершается с кодом выхода 1 (достал код возврата с помощью GetExitCodeProcess)

Вопросы:

1. Есть ли способ получить дополнительную информацию о том почему вылетел cmd.exe
2. В чём может быть различие в запуске с под вайна и с под виндовса (в обоих случаях запускал из консоли если это имеет разницу).

P.S:
Проверку на ошибки из кода убрал для краткости, все функции возвращаются успешно.

Comment: Дескрипторы пайпов наследуемые?

Comment: @Flammable, как видно из вызова я bInheritHandle в false установил.
Может я не правильно вопрос понял.

Comment: @Flammable, ну и LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes при создании анонимного пайпа я в NULL установил, на мсдн написано что при этом хендлы не могут быть наследуемыми.

Comment: Стоп, а может быть, банально file not found?

Comment: @VladD, file not found вы имели ввиду ошибку чью?
Если одна из функций винапи то всё что вызывал я сразуже проверял на ошибки, оказалось что всё исправно работает.
Падает по видимому дочерний процесс cmd.
В программе после вызова CreateProcess я в цикле происходит примерно так:
while ( WaitForSingleObject() == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
читаю/пишу в пайпы 
}
При выполнении на windows вовнутрь цикла ни разу не заходит и сразу возвращает wait_timeout

Comment: Я имел в виду, cmd.exe не найден. Попробуйте полный путь.

Comment: Тогда бы CreateProcess свалился с ошибкой. В любом случае на всякий пожарный проверил, не помогает:(.

Comment: @gg4me, а с каких пор можно не инициализировать `lpStartupInfo` предварительным вызовом `GetStartupInfo`?

Comment: @Flammable, я неправльно выразился. **Можно** не вызывать `GetStartupInfo`, но **нужно** инициализировать по крайней мере `STARTUPINFO::cb`.

Comment: @mega, я тоже неправильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дескрипторы пайпов должны быть наследуемыми:

> STARTF_USESTDHANDLES 0x00000100
>
> The hStdInput, hStdOutput, and
> hStdError members contain additional
> information.
>
> If this flag is specified when calling
> one of the process creation functions,
> **the handles must be inheritable** and the function's bInheritHandles
> parameter must be set to TRUE. For
> more information, see Handle
> Inheritance.

Подробности дальше:

> To enable a child process to inherit
> open handles from its parent process,
> use the following steps.
>
> Create the handle with the
> bInheritHandle member of the
> SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure set to
> TRUE.

В случае с [CreatePipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx) для этого необходимо в lpPipeAttributes передать ненулевой указатель.

> lpPipeAttributes [in, optional]
>
> A pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
> structure that determines whether the
> returned handle can be inherited by
> child processes. **If lpPipeAttributes
> is NULL, the handle cannot be
> inherited.**
>
> The lpSecurityDescriptor member of the
> structure specifies a security
> descriptor for the new pipe. If
> lpPipeAttributes is NULL, the pipe
> gets a default security descriptor.
> The ACLs in the default security
> descriptor for a pipe come from the
> primary or impersonation token of the
> creator.